# Is it considered a bad practice to have rows constantly changing in a SQL table?

Tags: sql

Is it considered a bad practice to have a table into which rows will be inserted and removed all the time and it may come to a point where this table will be empty? Basically, this table will reflect an actual occurrence in real life. Let me just take a very general(possibly bad) example to explain what I mean. I want to have a table which for example stores all the people currently inside a room. While they are in the room they will be present as a row in a table with some basic data. After they leave the room they will be removed from the roomTable and inserted into another table(roomLog) which stores a log of all the people who entered and leaved the room. Is this considered a bad design? If so what are the alternatives? Thank you very much.

Comment: Can the "people" be in multiple "rooms" at once?  And as an extension to that, will there be many different "room" tables?

Comment: @AaronDietz No there will be only one room, hence only one table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alternative is to use only your log table and use a status column or entered/exited date columns.

Which is preferred depends on what kinds of queries need to be performant, what indexes or unique constraints you may want to have, and what access rules need to apply to which tables.

To answer your abstract question of whether it is bad practice to have rows constantly changing, "No". An example would be a transactional queue. But know that inserts/delete are often slower than update.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your exact use case and specific database its difficult to say.

As Paul said the alternative would be using a single table with a Boolean flag "inRoom". People not in the room are considered to be historic (log) info.

The primary tradeoff is in the 2 table case you are performing 2 operations (a DELETE from the ROOM table and INSERT into LOG table). These are likely to be much slower than an UPDATE. Additionally, whatever DB based transactional logs you have are going to be chattier. On the plus side, you have a cleaner separation of data (its not fun to look into a DB table and have to filter everytime or see thousands of historical records).

How often are people entering/exiting? Do they move between states regularly or tend to enter and then never return? Do you have performance or space constraints?

All depends on your specifics, if its a toy problem/assignment, doesn't really matter.